# Spring Integration between two message brokers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am new to Spring-Integration.

My use case is:

Listen to a RabbitMQ queue/topic, get the message, process it, send it to other message broker (mostly it will be another RabbitMQ instance).

Expected load: 5000 messages/sec

In application.properties we can set configurations for one host.

How to use Spring Integration between two message brokers?

All the examples that i see are for one message broker. Any pointers to get started with two message brokers and Spring Integration.

Regards,

Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention an `application.properties` it sounds like you use Spring Boot with its auto-configuration feature. It is very important detail in your question because Spring Boot has opinion about auto-configuration and you really can have only one broker connection configuration auto-configured. If you would like to have an another similar in the same application, then you should forget that auto-configuration feature. You still can use the mentioned `application.properties`, but you have to manage them manually.

Since you talk about a RabbitMQ connection, so you need to exclude `RabbitAutoConfiguration` and manage all the required beans manually:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
```

You still can use the `@EnableConfigurationProperties(RabbitProperties.class)` on some your `@Configuration` class to be able to inject that `RabbitProperties` and populate respective `CachingConnectionFactory`. For the second broker you can introduce your own `@ConfigurationProperties` or just configure everything manually reading properties via `@Value`. See more info about manual connection factory configuration in Spring AMQP reference manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#connections

Comment: Thanks Artem. Let me try with your suggestions and get back.